# able to run the code through TERMINAL but getting time out error through IDE

Tags: command-line, ssh, python3, timeout

i am using

```
ssh.exeCommand("cd /root/newbuild/" + arg_obj["nbu_path"] + " && ./install < /tmp/NBU_10.3_response_master2")
```

and triggering a file for installation
when i run same command on my linux terminal it works fine

but when i run the same thing from my jenkins the python code is trigerring the same command and finishing the task but code is not fetching any exit code or maybe not getting out of the run itself in the backend and it throws below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 697, in recv
out = self.in_buffer.read(nbytes, self.timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/buffered_pipe.py", line 154, in read
raise PipeTimeout()
paramiko.buffered_pipe.PipeTimeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/NBUAutomation/nbu_qualification/stages/nbu_infoscale_proliferation/test_suits/NBU_main_instllation.py", line 18, in <module>
install_netbackup(cluster,version,add_node)
File "/root/NBUAutomation/nbu_qualification/stages/nbu_infoscale_proliferation/test_suits/netbackup.py", line 187, in install_netbackup
master_2_installation(args)
File "/root/NBUAutomation/nbu_qualification/stages/nbu_infoscale_proliferation/test_suits/nbu_install.py", line 510, in master_2_installation
m2_check = ssh_m2.exeCommand("cd /root/newbuild/" + arg_obj["nbu_path"] + " && ./install < /tmp/NBU_10.3_response_master2 && exit")
File "/root/NBUAutomation/nbu_qualification/stages/nbu_infoscale_proliferation/lib/misc/ssh_module.py", line 47, in exeCommand
'stdout' : stdout.read().decode().strip(),
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/file.py", line 184, in read
new_data = self._read(self._DEFAULT_BUFSIZE)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1359, in _read
return self.channel.recv(size)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 699, in recv
raise socket.timeout()
socket.timeout
```

i tried using extra argument && exit to exit the run after the task is completed still my installation is getting completed but unable to exit the code in backend and no help.

Comment: It looks like the ssh connection isn't being made? Authentication / authorisation issue? Apart from that, this looks to me more of an Jenkins or Paramiko issue than an Ubuntu issue.